# Get IP address of the client in C sockets

Tags: c, sockets, ip-address

How can I get the ip address of the client of which my server is connected to?
Here is how I accept incoming clients:

```
newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&clt_addr, &addrlen);
```

I tried the following:

```
 printf("ip is: %s\n", inet_ntoa(clt_addr.sin_addr));
```

But I am getting 127.0.0.1 which is not my ip address. Could it have something to do with me using localhost to test my client and server?

Comment: As far as localhost is concerned, 127.0.0.1 is your ip address.

Comment: so if i were not to use localhost, I would get an actual ip address?

Comment: @Rachelle yes if your application is hosted on a web and if someone access it..you'd get the actual IP. But now since your accessing it through your local host. Your IP would be 127.0.0.1

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is *always* your IP address, by definition. That's the address the client connected from, by connecting *to* 127.0.0.1 from within the same host. If the client had used another IP address you would get another IP address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could it have something to do with me using localhost to test my client and server?

Yes. If you connect to a server on localhost the client will also be localhost. This connection is not happening over the Internet, there is no network hardware involved, the client packets will come from localhost. This is known as [loopback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback#Virtual_loopback_interface) and occurs entirely in software.

If the client were to connect to the server using the server's external IP address it will have to do a connection via external routing and thus require a routable IP address.  For example, I can connect to a server on localhost, but I cannot using my routable IP address because my router blocks incoming connections.